# How to prove that this joint distribution is Gaussian without using probability densities?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, random-variable, joint-distribution, singular-matrix

> **Question:** I am wondering if there was a way to prove this result without using probability densities:
>
> If $\bf x \sim \mathcal N (m, P)$ and $\bf y \;|\; x \sim \mathcal N (Hx, R)$, then $$\begin{pmatrix}
> \bf x \\ \bf y
> \end{pmatrix}
> \sim \mathcal{N} \left(
> \begin{pmatrix}
> \bf m \\ \bf Hm
> \end{pmatrix}, 
> \begin{pmatrix}
> \bf P & \bf P H^{\top} \\ \bf HP & \bf H P H^{\top} + R
> \end{pmatrix}
> \right)$$

I came across the result [here on slide 14](https://users.aalto.fi/%7Essarkka/course_k2010/slides_3.pdf) some time ago. A sketch of a proof in the univariate case can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167385/prove-that-x-y-is-bivariate-normal-if-x-is-normal-and-y-conditionally-on-x-is).

The author of the slides uses the term "Gaussian densities" so the covariance matrices are non-singular. The author's choice of words may be harmless but it made me wonder about how a proof of the result would be when one cannot use probability densities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $(\bf y \;|\; x) \sim \mathcal N (Hx, R)$, $\bf y$ can be written as
 $$\bf y = \bf Hx + \bf \epsilon$$ where $\bf \epsilon \sim \mathcal N (0, R)$
and independent with $\bf x$. It means
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\bf x \\ \bf \epsilon \end{pmatrix} 
\sim \mathcal N \left (\begin{pmatrix}
\bf m \\ \bf 0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
\bf P & 0 \\ \bf 0 &\bf R
\end{pmatrix} \right )
$$

Then $$
\begin{pmatrix}
\bf x \\ \bf y
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
\bf I & 0 \\ \bf H &\bf I
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
\bf x \\ \bf \epsilon
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Following the fact that $$AY\sim N(A\mu, A\Sigma A') \text { given that } Y\sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$$
The results are there.